# Error al crear, ordenar e imprimir un array de punteros(?)

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Estoy intentando practicar con los arrays dinámicos, los punteros, los algoritmos de ordenación y el código separado por archivos pero...
No consigo saber por qué me sale el siguiente error..

[image: Aquí el error al ejecutar, el compilador no me da error.]

No estoy muy seguro si he usado bien el comando EXTERN, pero fue la única manera de que me compilara el código, si solo declaraba las variables en el cpp me daba un error que deia que no encontraba esas variables declaradas en el main... tengo un poco de lio mental.

Este es mi código en el archivo main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "WFlib.h"
using namespace std;


int main()
{

    queryData();
    sortData(pElem, nElem);
    showData(pElem, nElem);

    delete[] pElem;
    return 0;
}
```

Aquí el .h de la llibreria propia:

```
#pragma once

extern int* pElem;
extern int nElem;

void queryData();
void sortData(int*, int);
void showData(int*, int);
```

Y aquí, el cpp con el código de la libreria:

```
#include "WFlib.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int* pElem;
int nElem;

void queryData()
{
    cout << "Hola, por favor, introduce el numero de registros: ";
    cout << endl;
    cin >> nElem;
    pElem = new int[nElem];
    for (int i = 0; i < nElem; i++) {
        cout << "Introduce el valor para el registro [" << i << "]: ";
        cin >> *(pElem + i);
    }
}

void sortData(int* p_E, int n_E)
{
    int aux;
    for (int i = 0; i < n_E; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n_E; j++)
        {
            if (*(p_E + j) > * (p_E + j + 1)) {
                aux = *(p_E + j);
                *(p_E + j) = *(p_E + j + 1);
                *(p_E + j + 1) = aux;
            }
        }
    }
}

void showData(int* p_E, int n_E)
{
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Ordenado seria siendo: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n_E; i++)
    {
        cout << *(p_E+1) << " ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

He tenido que descargar la captura de pantalla y retocarla para poder empezar a ver lo que pone en la misma. En futuras preguntas evita usar capturas de pantalla, el ver un cacho de tu entorno de trabajo no aporta nada a la hora de proporcionar contexto a tu pregunta y es difícil trabajar con ella ya que no se puede copiapegar el texto ni hacer búsquedas de texto sobre la captura.

---

El error que recibes es claro y conciso, tal vez no lo entiendas por estar en inglés, te lo traduzco:

> CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer.

> CRT ha detectado que la aplicación escribió en memoria situada después del búfer del [montículo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mont%C3%ADculo_(inform%C3%A1tica)).

Básicamente, has utilizado memoria que tu programa no solicitó. Esto ha sucedido en la función `sortData`, en concreto en la condición en que compruebas si un elemento es mayor que el siguiente:

```
if (*(p_E + j) > * (p_E + j + 1)) {
    aux = *(p_E + j);
    *(p_E + j) = *(p_E + j + 1);
    *(p_E + j + 1) = aux;
}
```

La variable índice del bucle interno (`j`) va de `0` a `p_E - 1`, pero cuando estás en la última posición, las comprobaciones las haces sobre el elemento posterior al último. Si los azares de la memoria dan lugar a que en esa posición haya un valor menor al último elemento: intentarás intercambiar dichos valores.

En el ejemplo de tu desafortunada captura de pantalla, cuando `j` vale `1` haces la comprobación sobre `j + 1` (es decir: `2`), valor que está más allá del búfer que solicitaste.

Comment: Ante todo, disculpas por la chapuza de la captura.

Sí, entiendo el inglés. Pero tenía a sensación de que el error era por algún error declarando las variables entre archivos. 

No había visto el error en IF. Supongo q tendré que poner un -1 en las condición del For j.

Muchas gracias de verdad. Seguiremos aprendiendo :)